# unable to convert excel file into csv

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2010

Greeting

I have a big excel file with almost 48600 rows and 5000 columns. Data in my file look like this:

[image]

I am trying to convert this file to csv with **SAVE AS-->CSV** but no success.

how can I convert this file to csv?

thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to save it as a CSV file?

Comment: nothing, the file is saved as before

Comment: It won't work if you have multiple tabs. Delete all tabs except the one you want to save. If you have data on those tabs, you need to move them to their own files. CSV only supports one worksheet tab in a workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution above should work for you, however here is an alternative method you might try. I tested it on a file of ~25,000 rows and ~1200 columns.

```
Public Sub ExportToCSV()
    Dim fso As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim file As Object 'Scripting.File
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim tmp As Variant

    '## Modify this line to the destination path & filename of your exported file
    fileName = "C:\users\david_zemens\desktop\exported_file.csv"

    'Define the range of your worksheet
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'Create fileSystemObject & file output
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName)

    'Write each row to the file as a new line
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        tmp = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r.Value))
        file.WriteLine Join(tmp, ",")
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

It won't work if you have multiple tabs. Delete all tabs except the one you want to save. If you have data on those tabs, you need to move them to their own files. CSV only supports one worksheet tab in a workbook.

Method 2:  Import the Excel file into MS Access. Then select File -> Export -> as TXT file. In the filename field, enter ".csv" after the filename and click "Export All."

Comment: I have only one tab (worksheet) in a workbook

Comment: Do you have Google? Upload it to Google Drive and then try going to File, Download As, CSV. See if that works. I'm not sure why you're having trouble because from what you describe, it should be working.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but as I said, it is a big file, as a resualt I couldn't unpload the file

Comment: How big is the file in MB?

Comment: almost 140 MB xsl file

Comment: @Kaja, do you have MS Access?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40746/discussion-between-rwking-and-kaja)

Comment: I did it but I got this error: `Text file specification field seprator matches decimal seprator  or text delimiter` another problem is that Access only accepted the first 255 columns and not more, as I said I have much more columns in my excel file